# PHP imagemagick exec convert PDF page 0 to PNG is too small

Tags: php, imagemagick

I'm using this to convert a PDF to PNG:

`exec('/usr/bin/convert -density 96 -quality 85 a.pdf[0] a.png');`

I have also tried to make it as simple as this:

`exec('/usr/bin/convert -colorspace RGB "a.pdf[0]" "a.png"');`

but the source PDF file I gave has only one image and no text, and that image is 700x400 px size and still, the PNG that results is small as 100x30 for example.

How can I convert in order to result the original sized image? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Try reducing the density factor. That's a relative number - smaller density = larger output image.

Comment: Actually, if I setup density like this: -density 350% , I get the full sized, EXACT pixels image. How about that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the command along with "-density 350%" parameter. This gave me the exact picture size every time and has worked so far.

```
exec('/usr/bin/convert -density 350% -quality 85 a.pdf[0] a.png');
```

Thanks for you time.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this params for convert "-density 300x300 -units pixelsperinch". What about it?

Comment: This way I get a 429x429 px image from a 500x500 px source... Using 350% density, I get 500x500. I'm not saying that I'm so familiar with imagemagick's command parameters but I'm just telling the results. Thanks.